# Sql query using joins to find sum of quantity

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, inner-join

[image: Product table]

[image: billtran table]

Here,in billtran table the productid=1 is repeated twice

I want to find the `sum(billtran.quantity)` of each productid separately

[image: I want this output,the out expected my me is]

select Query1:

```
 select name,billtran.quantity from product inner join billtran on product.id=billtran.productid where product.id in(select id from product)
```

[image: Output of select query1]

Comment: Then, group by product name and sum the quantities

Comment: Please don't use images. Paste the tables and code as text here instead. A request shall be understandable without any picture. You *can* use images, too, but they shall only enhance the information (e.g. an added ERM diagram). Some people cannot even see your images, because they are blocked for them.

Comment: `product.id in (select id from product)`? What is this supposed to do? Make sure an ID read from the product table exists in the product table??? This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment:

```
select name, SUM(billtran.quantity) from product inner join billtran on product.id=billtran.productid where product.id in(select id from product)
GROUP BY NAME
```

My additions in caps

Note: `where product.id in(select id from product)` is an entirely useless where clause and should be removed. Queries don't have to have a where clause and don't need one that says a table id should be in all the ids in that table (always true)

I would hence have written this one as:

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  SUM(b.quantity) as sumof_quantity
FROM 
  product p
  INNER JOIN billtran b ON p.id=b.productid 
GROUP BY 
  p.name
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to get the sum of  the quantity according to the `product_id`

```
SELECT  product.name, SUM(billtran.quantity) AS value_sum 
    FROM billtran inner join product on product.id= billtran.product_id where product.id in(select id from product ) 
    GROUP BY product_id;
```

This will be the result:

```
name    quantity
abc      6
xyz      1
pqt      3
```

You can get the same result by grouping the `product.name` as well:

```
SELECT  product.name, SUM(billtran.quantity) AS value_sum 
FROM billtran inner join product on product.id=billtran.product_id where product.id in(select id from product) 
GROUP BY  product.name;
```

Comment: Your top query only works because it automagically picks a random product name per id; other enterprise grade dbs (and mysql in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode) wouldnt accept it

Answer (score 1):

Very simple query. Pls check below:
select product.name,sum(billtran.quantity) from product inner join billtran on product.id=billtran.productid group by billtran.productid